# Missing directories and files on npm install

Tags: node.js, git, npm, telegram

I'm trying to install [this module](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api) with `npm i --save https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api.git`.

The reason I avoid `npm i --save node-telegram-bot-api` is that I need some recently added methods (like `sendContact`).

When I install, it's added to my `package.json` as expected:

```
"node-telegram-bot-api": "git+https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api.git",
```

But when I try to run app that is using this module it says:

```
Error: Cannot find module './src/telegram'
```

After poking around a little bit it turned out that there is missing `src` and some other directories. Here is `tree` output:

```
$ tree ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api 
./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api
├── CONTRIBUTING.md
├── index.js
├── LICENSE.md
├── node_modules
(second one is skipped)
├── package.json
├── README.hbs
└── README.md
```

Why? And how can I fix it?

I tried to `npm cache clean` and `rm -rf ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api`, reinstalling, nothing helps.

Comment: After ~2 years I don't even understand what I was asking about...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the repository contains [`.npmignore` file](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/blob/master/.npmignore) and the following files and directories are ignored during installation:

```
# lcov
coverage/
*.log
.package.json

# artifacts & source
README.hbs
output.md
output/
src/
test/
examples/
lib-doc/

# dotfiles
.travis.yml
.eslintrc
.eslintignore
.editorconfig
.babelrc
.gitignore
.git
```

So if you want to use the latest version from the repository, you need to download it and install it manually. Like that:

```
cd ./node_modules
git clone https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api
cd ./node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api
npm install
```

**Upd.**: (imho) it is proper in this case to use a private registry for modules. For example [`sinopia`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia).

Comment: thanks! It makes sense. Btw, why do you think it's proper to use private registry? Can you clarify please? Thank you

Comment: @RomanPushkin Because in this case, you can transparently automate the update package from the git repository. And do not wait for when the upgrade package from `npmjs.com`.